# Show there exists a non-abelian group of order $pq$ without semi-direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

Let $p,q$ be primes with $p<q$ and $p \mid q-1$ . Show that there is a non-abelian group of order $pq$

By Sylow's theorems, we have $n_p=1 $ or $q$, and $n_q=1$.

However, if $n_p=1$, then both Sylow-p subgroup $P$ and Sylow-q subgroup $Q$ are unique and normal. By some work, we can see that $G$ is abelian.

So in order to show that there exists a non-abelian group of order $pq$, we must have $n_p=q$.

Thus, there are $q$ number of Sylow-p subgroups. Moreover, since $\gcd(q,p)=1$, for any Sylow-p subgroup $P$,  we must have $P \cap Q = \{ e\}$.

From here, I'm a bit stuck on showing that $G$ is non-abelian.

I've seen answers that require the use of semi-direct product. But I wonder if there is a way without using it.

Thanks!

Comment: What you describe as your argument does not really work because you need to *construct* a group. You cannot be "stuck on showing that $G$ in non-abelian" simply because you do not have any $G$!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_q$ is a finite field, so its multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_q^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $q-1$. Since $p\mid q-1=|\mathbb Z_q^{\times}|$, there is a unique subgroup $P\leq \mathbb Z_q^{\times}$ satisfying $|P|=p$. Now consider the group of linear polynomial functions $G=\{ax+b\in \mathbb Z_q[x]\;|\;a\in P, b\in \mathbb Z_q\}$ under the operation of composition.  By counting the number of choices for $a$ and $b$, derive that $|G|=pq$. Also, the linear function $t(x)=x+1\in G$ does not commute with $s(x)=ax\in G$ provided $a\neq 1$. There must exist such an $a\in P$, since $|P|=p>1$.

Comment: Very nice argument!

Comment: To be clear for the benefit of students, this is the semidirect product, just disguised somewhat. The more general fact is that the affine general linear group, consisting of affine transformations $x \mapsto Ax + b$ where $A \in GL_n(k), b, x \in k^n$, is a semidirect product $GL_n(k) \ltimes k^n$. Now one can restrict to subgroups to get other semidirect products.

Comment: Why doesn't $x+1$ commute with $ax$ here?  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Korn: $(s\circ t)(x) = a(x+1) = ax+a$, while $(t\circ s)(x) = (ax)+1 = ax+1$. If these composites/products were equal, then we would have $ax+a=ax+1$ for all $x\in \mathbb Z_q$. In particular, setting $x=0$ yields $a=1$. Since we have assumed $a\neq 1$, the polynomial functions $s$ and $t$ do not commute under composition.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a semi-direct product without saying that you are doing so, by a matrix trick. Namely, if $\mathbb Z/p$ is to (secretly?!?) act on $\mathbb Z/q$, for $x\in \mathbb Z/p$ and $y\in \mathbb Z/q$, heuristically map to $\pmatrix{x & y \cr 0 & 1}$... with the understanding that $xy$ means $y^x$, meaning exponentiation in $\mathbb Z/q$ by $x$ mod $p$. Of course, this is not well defined without hypotheses on $p,q$.

Answer (score 3):

It is a theorem that $$\langle a,b\mid a^p,b^q,aba^{-1}b^{-r}\rangle $$ is a presentation of a non-abelian group of order $pq$ when $p\mid q-1, r\ne1\pmod q$ and $r^p\equiv 1\mod q$.

---

It's easy to see that its order is at most $pq$;  as well as that it's non-abelian.

What remains is to show the order is $\ge pq$.  So, say $a^wb^x=a^yb^z$.  Then $a^{w-y}=b^{z-x}\implies w\equiv y\pmod p$ and $z\equiv x\bmod q$, because $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle =\{e\}$.  Thus we see that the elements $a^wb^x\,,0\le w\lt p,\,0\le x\lt q$ are all distinct.

---

Without the condition $r^p\equiv 1\pmod q$, it will turn out that $b=e$, and the group is then $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Again to be clear for the benefit of students, this is a presentation of a semidirect product of $C_p$ acting on $C_q$. The last relation should be read $aba^{-1} = b^r$.